# Not propagate usage requirements

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to [link against a library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) that has [usage requirements](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements) defined, but not use them?

Comment: Perhaps, but why do you want to? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I was thinking about include files with duplicit names in the library and your target.

Comment: And how would you actually deal with the problem? How would any file in your project decide which of the two it will get? Or is your actual problem about specifying the correct order of includes for all files in the target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake defines a shorthand way to satisfy all the *usage requirements* defined by the exported target **Upstream** in **Downstream**:

```
target_link_library(Downstream Upstream)
```

In the meantime, it is possible to extract the target properties separately, and use them in isolation, as you see fit.

Stricto-sensu, the "linking-against" is a usage requirement, so I assume you want to control which requirement to satisfy, and which you do not.

If you want to link against the library **Upstream**, you need to link against the libraries defined in the target `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARY` property. You can extract the linking requirement of an  EXPORTED target, even if it is `EXPORTED`, with the following code:

```
add_library(Downstream mylibrary.cpp) #Creates the Downstream library

# Extract Upstream's link interface
get_property(extracted_libraries TARGET Upstream PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
# And link Downstream against it
target_link_library(Downstream extracted_libraries)
```